# $\int_{0} ^{\infty}(\exp(-\exp(x))\log(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Find:$$\int_{0} ^{\infty}(\exp(-\exp(x))\log(x)dx$$
I know the integral converges, I checked with wolfram alpha too. I just do not know how to find the integral.I think Gamma function may help.

> Another version:$$Find:\int_{0}^{\infty}(2^{-2^x}log(x)) dx$$Question is given by J. Hajimir

Comment: What is the interval over which you want to integrate? $[1,\infty[$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{b}^{a}\log_{a}(x)dx=\frac{xln(x)-x}{ln(a)} $ where a is non-zero
and since $\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{{-e}^{x}}dx$ is an exponential integral, $Ei(x)$, which is the integral as follows $Ei(x) = -\int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac {e^{-u}}{u} du $. Substitute $e^x$ in to $u$. Since $\int \frac{1}{e^x}dx = \frac{x}{e^x}$ and $de^x = e^{x} dx$, one would obtain a solution of $-\frac{Ei(x)}{x}$. Multiply the integrals of $\log_{a}(x)$ and $e^{{-e}^{x}}$ to get your answer. I do not think an integral with lower bound 0 exists for that function. The non-elementary function $Ei(x)$ does actually converge, as shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Convergent_series. I'm not too sure of the accuracy of the answer, so anyone is welcome to edit. I hope in one way or another it answers your question. As for the sub-question you posed, substituting $u$ with $-ln(2^{-2^{x}})$ in $Ei(x)$ should work. In general the integral should not converge, I believe, since $ln(x)$ is divergent.

Comment: how about the lower bound is 1

Comment: I stated that ln(x) is divergent in the answer. However, if you are asking about the integral of only exp(-exp(x)), then refer to the link? The formula is really difficult to code in Latex

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: you mean this formula? $${\displaystyle E_{1}(z)=-\gamma -\ln z-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-z)^{k}}{k\;k!}}\qquad (|\operatorname {Arg} (z)|<\pi )}$$ The $\LaTeX$ code is contained in the information/properties of the image, this happen for almost any mathematical formula in wikipedia

Comment: Oh thanks for telling me! I thought all formulae in wikipedia can only be imported as images :)